# Strange XML document to parse

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse this XML code in IOS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ofertas>
    <oferta>
        <id>138</id>
        <connector/>
        <codigo>PARMAD</codigo>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Madrid, BordÈus e Paris]]></titulo>

        <descricao><![CDATA[ 7 dias c/ Pequeno AlmoÁo - Apenas Circuito Terrestre - Alojamento e Pequeno-AlmoÁo ; 7 dias c/ Pequeno AlmoÁo - SaÌda com voo de Lisboa - Alojamento e Pequeno-AlmoÁo ; 7 dias c/ Pequeno AlmoÁo - SaÌda com voo do Porto - Alojamento e Pequeno-AlmoÁo ; 7 dias c/ Pequeno AlmoÁo - SaÌda com voo de Faro - Alojamento e Pequeno-AlmoÁo]]></descricao>
        <datas><![CDATA[Consultar programa]]></datas>
        <data1>2012-07-31</data1>
        <data2>2013-03-23</data2>

        <categoria>Europa</categoria>
        <subcategoria>Circuitos Europa</subcategoria>
        <zona>Turistica</zona>
        <tipo>Circuitos Europa</tipo>

        <valor>575</valor>
        <dias>6</dias>

        <imagem>http://www.optitravel.net/optitravel/www/media/custom/cli_202/media/PKT_138_1343738358.jpg</imagem>

        <link/>

    </oferta>

    <oferta>
        <id>140</id>
        <connector/>
        <codigo>PARPRG</codigo>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Paris, Frankfurt e Praga]]></titulo>

        <descricao><![CDATA[ 7 dias c/ Pequeno AlmoÁo - Apenas Circuito Terrestre - Alojamento e Pequeno-AlmoÁo ; 7 dias c/ Pequeno AlmoÁo - SaÌda com voo de Lisboa - Alojamento e Pequeno-AlmoÁo ; 7 dias c/ Pequeno AlmoÁo - SaÌda com voo do Porto - Alojamento e Pequeno-AlmoÁo ; 7 dias c/ Pequeno AlmoÁo - SaÌda com voo de Faro - Alojamento e Pequeno-AlmoÁo]]></descricao>
        <datas><![CDATA[01/Nov, 08/Nov, 15/Nov, 29/Nov, 13/Dez, 27/Dez, 10/Jan/2013, 24/Jan/2013, 07/Fev/2013, 21/Fev/2013, 07/Mar/2013, 21/Mar/2013]]></datas>
        <data1>2012-08-01</data1>
        <data2>2013-03-21</data2>
```

I dont know if it's the best option to parse large files, but im using `SMXMLDocument` to parse this particular XML. The problem I'm having is that I can't decode this XML. Here is the code sample given by the author of the XML parser that I'm using:

```
  //REPLACED WITH MY XML DOC
NSString *sampleXML = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"global" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sampleXML];

// create a new SMXMLDocument with the contents of sample.xml
NSError *error;
SMXMLDocument *document = [SMXMLDocument documentWithData:data error:&error];

// check for errors
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error while parsing the document: %@", error);
    return;
}

// demonstrate -description of document/element classes
NSLog(@"Document:\n %@", document);

// Pull out the <books> node
SMXMLElement *books = [document.root childNamed:@"????"];

// Look through <books> children of type <book>
for (SMXMLElement *book in [books childrenNamed:@"????"]) {

    // demonstrate common cases of extracting XML data
    NSString *isbn = [book attributeNamed:@"id"]; // XML attribute
    NSString *title = [book valueWithPath:@"titulo"]; // child node value


    // show off some KVC magic
    NSArray *authors = [[book childNamed:@"authors"].children valueForKey:@"value"];

    NSLog(@"Found a book!\n ISBN: %@ \n Title: %@ \n Price: %f \n", isbn, title, price);
}
```

If there is a better XML parser for parsing this document please advise.

Comment: Hi, your question is not properly asked. You should add the code *you* tried, and give more detail about what's working and what's not. You said "i cant decode this XML", why ? You should look at the xml file associated to the sample code, and try to understand how it works.

Comment: I have tried this code in several ways to do it but i cant understand the XML document :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @AppleDelegate said, I also use TBXML Parser. Here is the code I would use. You'll need to import `TBXML+HTTP.h` before using it. Just call [self getXML] where you want, the code will do the rest.

First get the xml :

```
-(void)getXML {

    NSLog(@"Getting XML");

    // Create a success block to be called when the async request completes
    TBXMLSuccessBlock successBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument) {

        // If TBXML found a root node, process element and iterate all children
        if (tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement)
            [self traverseElement:tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement];

    };

    // Create a failure block that gets called if something goes wrong
    TBXMLFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument, NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"Error! %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    };

    // Initialize TBXML with the URL of an XML doc. TBXML asynchronously loads and parses the file.
    TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"File.xml"] 
                                      success: successBlock 
                                      failure: failureBlock];
}
```

Then read through the file :

```
- (void) traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element {

    TBXMLElement *oferta = element->firstChild;

    do {

        // Obtain first attribute from element
        TBXMLElement *element = oferta->firstChild;
        NSString *ofertaId = [NSString stringWithString: [TBXML textForElement:element]];
        NSLog(@"%@", ofertaId);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        // Nothing to do (<connector/>)

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *codigo = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", codigo);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *titulo = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", titulo);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *descricao = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", descricao);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *datas = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", datas);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *data1 = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", data1);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *data2 = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", data2);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *categoria = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", categoria);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *subcategoria = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", subcategoria);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *zona = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", zona);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *tipo = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", tipo);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *valor = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", valor);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *dias = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", dias);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *imagem = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", imagem);

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        // Nothing to do (<link/>)

        // Save infos

    } while ((oferta = oferta->nextSibling));

    NSLog(@"Done");
}
```

I have tested the code and it seems to work fine (run the code, and check the console logs). All you need to do is change `// Save infos` from my code to something where you save all the strings as you like. The do-while will go through all the `<oferta>` elements from the xml, and save all the elements you need in separate strings. You can then manipulate the strings to store dates, numbers and all.

Comment: Thanks for the Amazing help, but i noticed that this code gives a (null) value, is there any solution for this, since it has data associated with these particular elements,            the code:                    element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *titulo = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", titulo);  

        // Obtain the next element
        element = element->nextSibling;
        NSString *descricao = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@", descricao);

Comment: That's strange, I don't have it when I run the code. You should check how many times you go through the do-while when you get this error and check the xml. Do you just see *(null)* in the console ?

Comment: This XML was copied from windows and im using a mac, since some characters are not recognizable on mac i get strange characters on my XML, example: é , â, ã, í. I corrected them and the parse work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can opt for [TBXML Parser](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html).It aims to provide the fastest possible XML parsing whilst utilising the fewest resources.